# Maven test step is failing although verify step is working

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have a maven3 multi-module project and I want to execute the JUnit tests. Building the product works ok using `mvn clean verify`, also mvn integration-test is triggering my UITests just fine after the product is built.

But when I'm trying to trigger the JUnit tests with `mvn test` I'm getting the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxxx.commons: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   xxxx.commons:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   xxxx.library.common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of atlassian-public has elapsed or updates are forced ->
>   [Help 1]

I've put `xxxx.library.common` in my Plug-In Dependencies in Eclipse. Also it appears in *MANIFEST.MF* as Require-Bundle.

What am I missing? Why at the verify goal the dependencies are working fine and at test goal are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this. Some plugins couldn't be putted on atlassian repository so I've installed them manually in the repository using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project).